# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una comparación entre fechas en Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, date, kotlin

En la siguiente pantalla que muestro he querido hacer la siguiente funcionalidad. El usuario pulsa el **EditText Date**.

[image: New Event Screen]

A continuación se les abre un calendario para poder seleccionar la fecha.

[image: Calendar Screen]

Cuando seleccionan la fecha vuelven a la pantalla "*New Event*" y la fecha seleccionada aparece escrita en el **EditText Date**.
He querido diseñar la siguiente funcionalidad para poder escuchar los cambios que puedan suceder en este *EditText*, es decir, si el usuario introduce una fecha que sea mayor a la fecha actual que aparezca el *Switch* de notificación, pero si el usuario ha seleccionado una fecha más antigua que la actual, que no le aparezca el **Switch de Notificación**.

[image: New Event Screen with Date]

El problema que estoy teniendo es que con fechas cercanas al día de hoy, la lógica no está funcionando como debería provocando que se muestre o se esconda el *Switch* cuando debería, mientras que con fechas lejanas, me esta funcionando correctamente.

Dejo por aquí la lógica que estoy utilizando para poder hacer este proceso de comparar las fechas, y a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a sacar el error o si hubiera una manera más optima de poder hacerlo.

```
 binding.etDate.addTextChangedListener(){
            //Convetir a milisegundos la fecha del dia de hoy
            val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val currentDateMillis: Long = cal.timeInMillis

            //Convertir a milisegundos la fecha de creacion
            val cal2: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
            val dateCreated: Date = sdf.parse(binding.etDate.text.toString())
            cal2.time = dateCreated
            val dateCreatedMillis: Long = cal2.timeInMillis

            //Check
             if(currentDateMillis > dateCreatedMillis){
                binding.switchNotification.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                 binding.switchNotification.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes comparar fechas es utilizando los operadores `<`, `>` , `<=` y `>=` pero Kotlin sobrecarga estos operadores usando la funciòn `compareTo()`.

> El método  `compareTo()` devuelve:
>
> - Un número negativo si el objeto actual es menor que otro objeto
> - Un número positivo si el objeto actual es mayor que otro objeto
> - Cero si ambos objetos son iguales entre sí.

por lo tanto de acuerdo a lo anterior en tu còdigo se aplicarìa de esta forma:

```
 if(currentDateMillis.compareTo(dateCreatedMillis) > 0){ //currentDateMillis es mayor
    binding.switchNotification.visibility = View.GONE
 }else if(currentDateMillis.compareTo(dateCreatedMillis) == 0{
   //Son iguales
 }else if(currentDateMillis.compareTo(dateCreatedMillis) < 0){ //currentDateMillis es menor
   binding.switchNotification.visibility = View.VISIBLE
 }
```