# Problema con System.currentTimeMilis

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

estoy desarrollando una aplicación de calendario, y, busco que a la hora de enviar los datos haya ciertas restricciones, como que todos los campos estén rellenos, o que siempre que se guarde un evento sea mínimo un minuto después de la hora actual, a la hora de probarlo, he visto, que al meter el día actual, y compararlo con el día del sistema, siempre da error, y entra en el `if` que lo controla, dejo aquí abajo el código:

```
try {
    String horas = etFecha.getText().toString();
    String fechas = etFecha.getText().toString();

    if (fechas.equals("") || horas.equals("")) {
        aviso = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        aviso.show();
    } else {
        Date date = new Date(sdf.parse(fechas).getTime());
        Date date2 = new Date(sdfhora.parse(horas).getTime());

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > date.getTime()) {
            aviso = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            aviso.show();
        }
```

Al poner el mismo día, siempre entra en el último `if`, y no sé como arreglarlo, gracias.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de como introduces los valores de horas y fechas desde el EditText, únicamente debes comparar los valores de tipo Date, agregué una respuesta .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comprar 2 fechas te recomiendo usar: `Date.after()`, con lo que si `date2` es posterior a `date1`, `after` devuelve verdadero, de lo contrario devuelve falso.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String hora = etFecha.getText().toString();
String fecha = etFecha.getText().toString();
String fechaHora = fecha + " " + hora;

Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date2 = new Date(sdf.parse(fechaHora).getTime());

if (!date.after(date2)) {
    aviso = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    aviso.show();
}
```

De esta forma puede comprobar si es igual o posterior a la del sistema. Asegúrate también de comprobar que la hora del dispositivo es la de tu franja horaria, no vaya a ser que sea eso lo que te esté fallando.

**Edición**

Por ejemplo, para:

> Fecha introducida: 2021-12-31 23:59:59
> Fecha del sistema: 2021-10-27 23:59:59

Como la actual no es posterior a la introducida se mostrará el aviso con `Toast`.

Comment: He intentado tanto este método como el de abajo, y me sigue pasando lo mismo, a la hora de poner el mismo día, siempre me salta el toast de que la fecha es incorrecta, no sé si es porque falte la hora o que.

Comment: He incluido la hora en la fecha cuando se comprueba, es muy probable que fuese por eso.

Comment: Incluye un ejemplo de lo que escribes en los edittext, si no es correcto el formato no se podrá realizar la comparación.

Comment: Ya está arreglado, muchas gracias a ambos, era por la hora y un fallo en el formato, con eso ya estaría, gracias ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Para comparar 2 valores de tipo Date** no puedes usar los operadores <, > , <= y >= , puedes usar el método `compareTo()` :

el método `compareTo()`  devuelve:

- Un número negativo si el objeto actual es menor que otro objeto
- Un número positivo si el objeto actual es mayor que otro objeto
- Cero si ambos objetos son iguales entre sí.

Por lo tanto en tu comparación sería:

```
     //if (System.currentTimeMillis() > date.getTime()) {
     Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
     if (date.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
        aviso = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        aviso.show();
    }
```

Si deseas comparar fechas en Kotlin, también puedes usar la funciòn `compareTo()`

[**¿Cómo puedo realizar una comparación entre fechas en Kotlin?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/491258/95)